# Calling a C# method from Javascript and executing the code inside the

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a Javascript function I am calling from C# code behind when a user clicks an  OnRowDeleting call from a GridView. Here is that Call and method

```
 OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting"
 protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {  
       ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "hwa", "Ealert();", true);       
    }
```

It then calls that JS code and asks a question to the user. Based on whether they hit yes or no. I need it the JS to send a call to a C# method. Here is the JS code and the C# code that it is supposed to call.

```
<script> ...JS..
    function Ealert() {
            //var test = document.getElementById("hdField");
            bootbox.confirm({
            message: "Did you send the renewal email associated with this client?",
            buttons: {
                confirm: {
                    label: 'Yes',
                    className: 'btn-success'
                },
                cancel: {
                    label: 'No',
                    className: 'btn-danger'
                }
            },
                callback: function (result) {
                    if (result == true) {
                        bootbox.alert({
                            message: "Thank you",
                            size: 'medium'
                        });
                      // document.getElementById('<%=hdField.ClientID %>').value = "true"; 
                    } else {
                            bootbox.alert({
                            message: "Please go back to your saved location\n and send the renewal email.",
                            size:'small'
                        });
                        // document.getElementById('<%= hdField.ClientID %>').value = "false";
                        PageMethods.testCSharp();
                        function onSuccess(result) {
                        alert(result);
                         }

                         function onFailure(result) {
                         alert("Failed!");
                        }

                    }                        
                    console.log('This was logged in the callback: ' + result);

                }          
        });
    }
```

C#

```
 [WebMethod]
    public static void testCSharp(bool result, GridView GridView1, object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool variable = result;
        string t = result.ToString();

        MessageBox.Show(t);

        string UniqClient = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
        string UniqPolicy = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text;
        string emailed = "No";
        string query = "UPDATE [Reviewed_Renewal_Policy] SET [Emailed] = @emailed where where ([UniqClient] = @UniqClient) AND ([UniqPolicy] = @UniqPolicy)";

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=GTU-BDE01;Initial Catalog=GTU_Apps;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
            {
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UniqClient", UniqClient);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UniqPolicy", UniqPolicy);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailed", emailed);
                conn.Open();
                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
            }
        }


        return;

    }
```

The issue is the PageMethods call to this method never works. I was receiving and error that PageMethods wasn't setup correctly, but changing the method to public static void fixed it. However, it executes nothing in the method itself.

I had the SQL query commented out and used the MessageBox.Show as a test, but it doesn't work. Does anyone have any idea why or how I can have this code executed based off what option is chosen in the JavaScript? Thanks for the help

Comment: You are exposing your C# method as a web method, you would have to call the web method using AJAX. You can't call backend C# methods in a one liner javascript.

Comment: MessageBox.Show is a very bad idea in a web application. That's for Windows Forms, not ASP.NET. If you want to see if some code got reached, add proper logging to your application, such as via [Serilog](https://serilog.net/) or [NLog](https://nlog-project.org/).

Comment: mason, that doesn't really answer my question, but alright. Additionally, MessageBox.Show is purely a test. Not actually using. I needed to see if anything was being returned. I've used it for other similar tests and works perfectly fine for what I've used it for.

Comment: Wurd, don't suppose you have an example ?

Comment: Wurd, Think I found something. Like this,   $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: 'ReviewedPolicyEmail.aspx/testCSharp',
         data: "",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (msg) {
             $("#divResult").html("success");
         },
         error: function (e) {
             $("#divResult").html("Something Wrong.");
         }
     });
   }

Comment: Only problem is, the server is forcing a username and password sign on, but won't register the as correct. So it looks like Ajax is out.

Comment: AJAX is the only way to call a WebMethod from a web page

Comment: ADyson, I found an example of Ajax to use, but it causes our intranet server to request a username and password sign on. However, even after reentering that info it doesn't seem to work. I'm sure there is a setting of some type that circumvents that, but I haven't found it

Comment: what kind of authentication does your server use? If it's Windows Authentication (i.e. Kerberos or NTLM) then you can specify the option `xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },` in jQuery $.ajax()

Comment: 1. Ideally you should not call  web method directly but using AJAX. 2. But if you want to go with same approach then you have to match the methods parameters. 3. So your method should be `public static void testCSharp()` then it will get called using `PageMethods.testCSharp()`. This is the issue with PageMethods calls that you have to pass the data in basic formats only(No complicated objects). So Use JSON with ajax and then process that data.

Comment: @Wurd Yes we can call the web method using `PageMethods`. Although I agree that it is not a good way to do things.

Comment: I'm all for doing it another way however, I've not come across this before and through my searching, using webmethods was the most common way. I need to call a server side method based off the Yes or No JavaScript button selection. Unfortunately, using the Ajax way causes our intranet server to repeatedly request a username and password dialog box however, never accepts the pair as correct. An additional issue I've not been able to dive into. Is there an alternative to webmethods?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an Ajax call in order send a value to your C# function.

```
    $.ajax({
    data: formData,
    method: "Post",
    url: url,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function (d) {
       SuccessMessage(successMsg);
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        ErrorMessage(errorMsg);
    }
});
```

Something similar to this. URL will be the path to your c# method.

Comment: Thanks for the example. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work on my end. I've found that exact example in multiple places, but for I've not seen it work correctly yet. The issue is it causes our intranet server to continuously pop up our log in dialog box and if with correct credentials it doesn't recognize them. ADyson above suggested xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }, but sadly this doesn't seem to mitigate the issue either. Thanks for the help.

Comment: That is probably because you are trying to call a function that exists somewhere on the server. The only reason Ajax would require credentials in if a cross-site request is made.

Comment: xhrFields: { withCredentials: true } is suppose to indicate whether you can make cross-site Access control request using credentials. Normally it is set to false by default. If using this is also not working then maybe double check the credentials.

Comment: Also you can refer to this link it might help you understand what is causing you this problem. [link](https://techblog.constantcontact.com/software-development/using-cors-for-cross-domain-ajax-requests/)